# Node-JS convert mp4 to m3u8 with FFMPEG : Unable to find a suitable output format for 'v:1,a:1"'

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, mp4, m3u8

I am writing a server-side function to convert a mp4 file to m3u8, but there is an error with the differents video size. I want to have my video in differents sizes (4k UHD, 2k, 1080p, 720p...) but, with this line : `"-var_stream_map", "'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1'",`, there is an error :

> [NULL @ 0x7fe9de00d800] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'v:1,a:1"'
> v:1,a:1": Invalid argument

When I delete this line, all work, but I have just the v0 in 640x360 and not the v1 (960x540).

How can I bypass this error to have all the video sizes ?

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var infs = new ffmpeg

infs.addInput(doc.data().url).outputOptions([
            '-preset slow', '-g 48', '-sc_threshold 0',
            '-map 0:0', '-map 0:1', '-map 0:0', '-map 0:1',
            '-s:v:0 640x360', '-c:v:0 libx264', '-b:v:0 365k',
            '-s:v:1 960x540', '-c:v:1 libx264', '-b:v:1 2000k',
            "-var_stream_map", "'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1'",
            '-master_pl_name master.m3u8',
            '-f hls', '-hls_time 6', '-hls_list_size 0',
            '-hls_segment_filename fileSequence%d|v%v.ts',
            '-max_muxing_queue_size 1024',
        ]).output('./video.m3u8')
            .on('start', function (commandLine) {
                console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
            })
            .on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message, err, stderr);
            })
            .on('progress', function (progress) {
                console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done')
            })
            .on('end', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log('Finished processing!' /*, err, stdout, stderr*/)
            })
            .run()
```

Comment: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#specifying-multiple-outputs  : fyi the docs of fluent for multi-out are a bit diff than your use of output maps. if the maps wont work, try adding ".output sections "  to your fluent expression

Comment: did you find its solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also facing same problem which resolved by putting `var_stream_map` in another `outputOption(option...)`.

```
    infs.addInput(doc.data().url)
        .outputOptions([option...])
        .outputOption('-var_stream_map', 'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1') ...
```